# Custom namer oneuploadBundle Symfony

Tags: symfony, dropzone.js, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm trying to use dropzone with 1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle.
Upload is working well, and I'm trying to use my custom namer.
My configuration:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        products:
            namer: app.upload_namer
            use_orphanage: true
            frontend: dropzone
            storage:
                directory: "%kernel.root_dir%/../data/products/"
```

Service conf

```
app.upload_namer:
    class: AppBundle\Uploader\Naming\UploadNamer
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
```

My Namer:

```
class UploadNamer implements NamerInterface
{

    private $tokenStorage;
    private $productName;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage){
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a user directory name for the file being uploaded.
     *
     * @param FileInterface $file
     * @return string The directory name.
     */
    public function name(FileInterface $file)
    {
        $userName = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        return sprintf('%s/%s.%s',
            $userName,
            uniqid(),
            $file->getExtension()
        );
    }

}
```

I need to pass a folder name ($productName) to my namer, so I can use it to create storage folder:

```
 products/$userName/$productName/$filename.ext
```

This variable will come from my form:

```
formData.append("productName", "loremipsum");
```

How can I can retrieve this parameter from my Namer ?

Thank you!

Comment: You can add servise parameters. arguments: ["@security.token_storage", "other_param"] and __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, $param)

Comment: Thanks @Ramazan , and how can I pass this variable when calling the service ?

Comment: Service parameters are static and can not be changed dynamically.
Try adding a parameter to the function you want to call?

Comment: Okay, and when can I call my service to set property ? in which file / stage ?